# Is this matrix ring semisimple?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, semi-simple-rings

I'm trying to solve the following problem.

> Let $\mathbb{C}$ be the complex numbers and $\mathbb{C}[x]$ the polynomial ring over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$. For which $n\geq 1$ is the ring
>   $R_n:=\begin{bmatrix}
> \frac{\mathbb{C}[x]}{((x-\alpha)^n)} && \frac{\mathbb{C}[x]}{((x-\alpha)^n)} \\
> \frac{\mathbb{C}[x]}{((x-\alpha)^n)} && \frac{\mathbb{C}[x]}{((x-\alpha)^n)} 
> \end{bmatrix}$
>   semisimple?

Here the definition of a semisimple ring:

> A ring $R$ is called semisimple if $R$ as a module over itself is a sum of simple $R$-submodules of $R$. A module $M$ is called simple if the only submodules of $M$ are $(0)$ and $M$.

So far I have that it is semisimple for $n=1$. The submodules of $R_1=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\mathbb{C}[x]}{(x-\alpha)} && \frac{\mathbb{C}[x]}{(x-\alpha)} \\
\frac{\mathbb{C}[x]}{(x-\alpha)} && \frac{\mathbb{C}[x]}{(x-\alpha)} 
\end{bmatrix}$ are of the form $\begin{bmatrix}
I && 0 \\
I && 0 
\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}
0 && I \\
0 && I  
\end{bmatrix}$ where $I$ is an ideal of $\frac{\mathbb{C}[x]}{(x-\alpha)}$. Since $\frac{\mathbb{C}[x]}{(x-\alpha)}\simeq \mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ is a field, we know that $I$ is either $(0)$ or $\frac{\mathbb{C}[x]}{(x-\alpha)} $. Thus, $I$ is simple and

$\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\mathbb{C}[x]}{(x-\alpha)} && \frac{\mathbb{C}[x]}{(x-\alpha)} \\
\frac{\mathbb{C}[x]}{(x-\alpha)} && \frac{\mathbb{C}[x]}{(x-\alpha)} 
\end{bmatrix}\simeq \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\mathbb{C}[x]}{(x-\alpha)} && 0 \\
\frac{\mathbb{C}[x]}{(x-\alpha)} && 0 
\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
0 && \frac{\mathbb{C}[x]}{(x-\alpha)} \\
0 && \frac{\mathbb{C}[x]}{(x-\alpha)} 
\end{bmatrix}$.
Hence, the ring $R_1$ is semi simple.

Is this correct so far? And how can I proceed for $n>1$? I know that $\frac{\mathbb{C}}{((x-\alpha)^n)}$ is not a field since the ideal is not maximal but I don't know what I should do next.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Wederburn's theorem, if your ring is semisimple, it is isomrphic to $\prod M_{n_i}(D_i)$ where the $D_i$'s are division algebras over $\Bbb{C}$. But the only division algebra over the complex numbers is $\Bbb{C}$.

So your ring is semisimple iff it is isomrphic to $\prod M_{n_i}(\Bbb{C})$. But for $n>1$, these rings have non-isomorphic center.

So your ring is semisimple iff $n=1$.

Comment: Do the rings have non-isomorphic center because $Z(\prod M_{n_i}(\mathbb{C}))$ is a product of fields and $Z(R_n)$ is only for $n=1$  a product of fields?

Comment: Well, $Z(R_n)\cong C[x]/(x-a)^n$ and Z(\prod M_{n_i}(C))\cong \prod C$ and they are clearly not isomorphic.

Comment: Just to be sure: You used the following version of Wederburn's theorem: A semisimple algebra over a field $K$ is isomorphic to $\prod M_{n_i}(D_i)$ with $D_i$ finite-dimensional division algebras over $K$. And you used that the ring $R_n$ is an algebra over $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Yes exactly. If I remember correctly, the theorem also requires the algebra to be finite dimensional, which is the case here.

Answer (score 3):

Set $A=\mathbb{C}[x]/((x-\alpha)^n)$. Then $A$ is a commutative artinian local ring, with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}=(x-\alpha)/((x-\alpha)^n)$. So your question can be generalized to whether the matrix ring
$$
M_2(A)=\begin{bmatrix}
A & A \\
A & A
\end{bmatrix}
$$
is semisimple, where $A$ is a commutative artinian local ring, with maximal ideal $M$. Let's show that the ideal
$$
M_2(\mathfrak{m})=\begin{bmatrix}
\mathfrak{m} & \mathfrak{m} \\
\mathfrak{m} & \mathfrak{m}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
consists of left quasi-regular elements; an element $r$ in a ring $R$ is left quasi-regular if $1-r$ is left-invertible. So, suppose $u,v,x,y\in \mathfrak{m}$ and let's look for an inverse of
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1-u & -v \\
-x & 1-y
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Since $1-u-y+uy-vx$ is invertible in $A$, because $u+y-uy+vx\in \mathfrak{m}$, we're done because the matrix has invertible determinant.

Thus the given ideal is contained in the Jacobson radical of the ring; a semisimple ring has zero Jacobson radical, so a necessary condition for the ring to be semisimple is that $\mathfrak{m}=0$. In your case, it boils down to $n=1$.

---

Perhaps simpler: the ideal $M_2(\mathfrak{m})$ is not a direct summand. If it were, it would be generated (as a left or right module) by an idempotent $e$; but, as we saw, $1-e$ would be an idempotent invertible, so $1-e=1$ and $e=0$.

Comment: Thanks. That was very helpful. Is there also a way to show this without using local rings and Jacobson radical? I'm studying for an exam and we just had the definition of semisimple and that being semi simple is equivalent to (1) being a direct sum of simple modules and (2) for every submodule N there exists a submodule P such that M=N+P.

Comment: @chwhite You can show that the ideal is not a direct summand of the ring.

Comment: Do you mean the maximal ideal which you denoted with M?

Comment: @chwhite No, the ideal $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}M&M\\M&M\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ in the matrix ring.

Comment: @chwhite I added the proof without the Jacobson radical. As you see it uses just the characterization with direct summands.